# Table loop if not checked checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a condition to check if the checkbox is not selected. If so, there should be a `prompt` or `alert` that user must choose a checkbox.

```js
function submit() {
  var row_count = $('#adj_table_x >tbody >tr').length;
  var grid = document.getElementById("adj_table_x");
  var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

  // I want to put a condition here before the loop value will inserted

  for (var i = 1; i <= row_count; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
      var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
      var data = row.cells[1].innerHTML;

      $.post('../controller/controller.php?action=submit', {
        'data': data
      }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What checkbox? Or any checkbox?

Comment: if the user submit the button and it didnt choose any of checkbox it will not proceed

Comment: Another thing if you have data in your table then you can also assign data in each `td` with a hidden input field, and then you can give same name or same class to each hidden input, then you can target those values with the class name easily which will give you selected values, whether empty or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below selector
$("input:checked").length != $("input").length

You can tweak the code based on your requirement

You need to use pseudo selector 'checked' available in JQuery - Please see the link below for more info

https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
function submit (){
   if($("#tableID input[type='checkbox']:checked").length != 
   $("#tableID input[type='checkbox']").length){
      alert("please check all values")
   }
  else{
    //Put your code here
  }
```

Comment: the data comes from the table not on form.

Comment: I think this should work,$("#tableID input:checked").length != $("#tableID input").length

Comment: To be specific on checkbox you could refine the selected                       
$("#tableID input[type='checkbox']:checked").length != $("#tableID input[type='checkbox']").length

Comment: where do I put it sir?

Comment: Is the solution Working?

Comment: Can you provide the updated code screenshot with html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, not really sure about your explanation, but see if it works for you.

```
function submit() {
var row_count = $('#adj_table_x >tbody >tr').length;
var grid = document.getElementById("adj_table_x");
var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

// I want to put a condition here before the loop value will inserted
if(checkBoxes.prop('checked') == false){
  alert('Please select checkbox');
  return false;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= row_count; i++) {
if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
  var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
  var data = row.cells[1].innerHTML;

  $.post('../controller/controller.php?action=submit', {
    'data': data
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
   });
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: its error sir. it says "Uncaught TypeError: checkBoxes.prop is not a function"

Comment: yes, it's because of mulitple checkboxes, please refer to @ANSJSO answer